# Android emulator not taking full screen size

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

setting andorid emulator for the first time, but have this problem, cant find a way to resize the emulator, and even if I use the arrows to resize it will have the same aspect ratio.

any help appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Emulator can't really be resized (with changes to aspect ratio) on the fly, you'd have to modify the virtual device profile https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds with your custom screen size.

Comment: @Martheen do you know what specific setting do I need to change?
tried with screen size and resolution but none worked